# AWS CDK: Set name for elasticache parameter group (Python flavour)

Tags: aws-cdk

I am trying to set a name for `elasticache.CfnParameterGroup` to comply with some IAM permissions boundaries (names must start with a prefix, e.g. `my-project`. Right now I am attempting the following with "description" argument:

```py
import aws_cdk.aws_elasticache as elasticache
# ...
parameter_group = elasticache.CfnParameterGroup(
    main,
    "RedisParameterGroup",
    description="my-project-param-group",
    cache_parameter_group_family="redis6.x",
)
```

This does not work because it doesn't set the param group name to the correct prefix.

So, I can't find any "naming" parameter for the constructor. I tried adding a tag such as `tags=[{"key": "Name", "value": "my-project-param-group"}],` but that still doesn't actually give the parameter group a name. The help text for `CfnParameterGroup` says:

```
def __init__(self,
             scope: Construct,
             id: str,
             *,
             cache_parameter_group_family: str,
             description: str,
             properties: IResolvable | Mapping[str, str] | None = None,
             tags: Sequence[CfnTag | dict[str, Any]] | None = None) -> None
```

Which doesn't show any naming parameter. Most other constructs seem to have some kind of naming parameter, e.g. the actual `CfnCacheCluster` has `cluster_name` - what is the equivalent for the parameter group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it, because it currently appears to be omitted in cloudformation.

Starting with [the CDK's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticache/README.html), where it says,

> Use the automatically generated L1 constructs, in the same way you would use [the CloudFormation AWS::ElastiCache resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ElastiCache.html) directly.

So then we look at [`AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-parametergroup.html) where it makes no mention of `CacheParameterGroupName`.

Finally we can verify in the documentation for the underlying API call [CreateCacheParameterGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCacheParameterGroup.html) where `CacheParameterGroupName` is a required parameter.  So it appears that cloudformation's implementation of ParameterGroup does not support a user-defined name.

Sorry, I think you're SOL on that one.  Thankfully parameter groups are  pretty straight forward, so you might want to consider having the administrators create them externally.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that in detail. Yeah, I'll look at an alternative way of handling it.